# When are facebook actions displayed in the news feed and timeline?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-timeline

As a facebook app developer, you usually try to create as much exposure as possible to other facebook users. I'm trying to better understand some of the factors involved:

**Aggregations**

Facebook states that aggregations appears on a user's timeline based on data availability and feedback ([source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-aggregation/))

- Does it mean you are never certain if your aggregation will be displayed?

**Mention Tagging & Action Tagging**

When you tag a friend of the user of your app:

- Will that action always appear on that friend's neews feed?
- Will that action always appear on the friends timeline (as long as they allow friends to publish on their wall)?

Comment: Read this article for a glimpse at some of the logic behind how Facebook presents data to users. http://www.technologyreview.com/featuredstory/428150/what-facebook-knows/ => TLDR: We're all lab rats in a big social engineering experiment.

Comment: thanks cpilko, this article is very interesting. What I'm trying to understand, however is just what other users see when you publish an action.

Comment: They see what Facebook wants you to see. Facebook has decided not to show me my wife's posts and the posts of pages I admin before. You're never guaranteed to see *anything* on Facebook.